# Connection between non Unreal server and Unreal client

Tags: c++

Assume the situation, that I made my own server with c++ ,based on multithreading.Than I connect client which is made by Unreal and it works successfully. Next, I want to calculate some physical operating in my own server, not using Unreal's function "Collision hull" .

So this is my main question, 
is this possible that server can receive float type datas, from Unreal client which is compute for physical operating. 
I just really wonder about this, because Unreal deny to fixing their code.

I am sorry that I am not good enough in English. Thanks.

+Not Blueprint .

Comment: Please, have a look at [Unreal Engine @ github](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github). If you have to fix something in their physics engine, you may do it in the source code. Heard, they accept pull-requests as well.

Comment: Oh, If that so, than I missed it. Ok , I'll keep finding it. Thanks

Comment: Regardless, the solution you outline is feasible. What specifically are you having an issue with?